# Clickhouse : convert datetime toUnixTimestamp depend on multiple Timezone

Tags: clickhouse

I'm looking for an alternative to convert datetime at different local place into UnixTimestamps.

Here my test code:

```
CREATE TABLE val(`datetime` String, `timezone_place` String) ENGINE = TinyLog;
INSERT INTO val VALUES ('2021-12-26 18:00:00', 'GMT'), ('2021-12-26 19:00:00', 'Europe/Paris');
SELECT *, toUnixTimestamp(datetime, timezone_place) as unixTimestamp from val;
```

In the third column "unixTimestamp", I would like to obtain the same value of unix timestamps in two rows.

However, I got an message error :
*>>> Query ERROR: Code: 44. DB::Exception: Illegal type of argument #2 'timezone' of function toUnixTimestamp, expected const String, got String: While processing datetime, timezone_place, toUnixTimestamp(datetime, timezone_place) AS unixTimestamp. (ILLEGAL_COLUMN) (version 21.12.2.17 (official build))*

Answer (score 0):

as expected:

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#totimezone

*timezone — Timezone for the returned value. String. This argument is a constant, because toTimezone changes the timezone of a column (timezone is an attribute of DateTime* types).

---

There is no simple solution using Clickhouse. Clickhouse assumes you do this in your application.

Comment: for others to know, it was implemented in version 23.9 https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/53680