# formatDateTime in ClickHouse gives argument error when working with non-constant timezones, when it shouldn't

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to change a datetime fields in ClickHouse table according to a specific timezone.
Firstly I tried to use a toTimeZone with a second argument as a timezone in string format, but as I found out, it's not possible to have a different timezones in one column, and in my case they are dynamic.

Simplified example:

```
select
    toTimeZone(t.task_date, tz.timezone) as task_date
from tasks_and_stores t
inner join timezones tz on t.store = tz.store
```

It is giving an error "*Illegal type of argument #2 'timezone' of function toDateTime, expected const String, got String*", which as I read in [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions#totimezone) and in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70594771/4643681), is expected.

I was looking for a way to use a dynamic datetime change, and saw in docs below the toDateTime part that "[formatDateTime](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions#formatDateTime) - supports non-constant timezone."

So tried to use it, in such a way:

```
select
    formatDateTime(t.task_date, '%F %T', tz.timezone) as task_date_tz
from tasks_and_stores t
inner join timezones tz on t.store = tz.store
```

But what is surprising, is not only that it gives me an error "*DB::Exception: Argument at index 2 for function formatDateTime must be constant.*", which is kinda not expected, but that even an example query in docs themselves

```
SELECT
    now() AS ts,
    time_zone,
    formatDateTime(ts, '%T', time_zone) AS str_tz_time
FROM system.time_zones
WHERE time_zone LIKE 'Europe%'
LIMIT 10
```

gives the same error!
[image: Query from docs which isn't working]
It definitely shouldn't have falied, as it even has an example of the output there in docs themselves. And it works if I just put a string like 'Europe/Amsterdam' there in 3rd argument. Really confused about that all. Did somebody solve this problem before somehow? Thanks!

ClickHouse Version: 23.8

Comment: Maybe the docs need updating? timezone has to be a constant: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/6948

Comment: it was implemented in 23.9

v23.9.1.1854 * SQL functions "toString(datetime)" and "formatDateTime()" now support non-constant timezone arguments. [#53680](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/53680) ([Yarik Briukhovetskyi](https://github.com/yariks5s)).

Comment: 23.9 https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/0fec1cea-b8cd-4120-a7a2-4a90ec13c7ac

Comment: I see.. thanks! yeah, the docs should be updated for sure

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work in clickhouse 23.8, you should update it to 23.9.

Comment: I see... do you have any idea for the workaround if version can't be updated to 23.9 for now? or there is just no way to get around this on db level?

Comment: unfortunately i didnt found a workaround